# The `Adapter.Update (DataTable);` method updates all rows of the table data source or only those rows that have been modified?

Tags: c#, ado.net

The `Adapter.Update (DataTable);` method updates all rows of the table data source or only those rows that have been modified?

Logics:
- connect to the database;
- we carry out sampling of rows of tables;
- the user makes changes;
- Saves. Method `Save()`.

I use code to work with the database:

```
public DataTable CreateCmds()
        {
            table_2 = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                string connectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS1;Initial Catalog=Prb;Integrated Security=True";              

                string queryString = "SELECT * FROM tbl_01_Groups";
                // string connectString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=LSTU_Schedule_autumn20172018;" + "Integrated Security=true;";

                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
                    adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
                    SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);

                    connection.Open();

                    adapter.Fill(table_2);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                string s = ex.Message;
                string t = ex.StackTrace;
                // throw;
            }

            return table_2;
        }

        public void Save()
        {
            string connectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS1;Initial Catalog=Prb;Integrated Security=True";

            string queryString = "SELECT * FROM tbl_01_Groups";

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
                adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
                SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);

                connection.Open();

                adapter.Update(table_2);
            }
        }
```

**Update_1**
I did not find the answer on the network, the solution to this question.
The question is caused by the increased efficiency of the code.
I thought that when executing the expression `adapter.Update(DataTable)`, the code iterates through all the rows of the data source table.
If this is the case, then there are probably more efficient ways to sample the code to update only the line that was changed.

Comment: The answer is obvious and covered in docs and tutorials since 2002. Why the question? Did you encounter another problem and somehow thought that the adapter updated every row? Your code doesn't make any changes to `table_2` so there shouldn't be *any* updates

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Updated question

Comment: The answer is mentioned in every tutorial since 2002. By now there are *hundreds* of tutorials that explain how ADO.NET works. For example, [Updating Data Sources with DataAdapters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/updating-data-sources-with-dataadapters) explains what's going on. If in doubt though, just use SQL Server Profiler to check the commands executed when you call `Update()`

Comment: Instead of guessing or assuming, go through a tutorial or course. ADO.NET knowledge is required for .NET certification so it's *very* well covered by courses too. You can get three months free access to Pluralsight's courses through the (also free) [Visual Studio Dev Essentials](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/dev-essentials/) program. Check the [ADO.NET Fundamentals](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/adodotnet-fundamentals) course which explains how ADO.NET works in general

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataTable.Rows[index].RowState refer to the state of the data row.

ADO.NET will check the state, only update when state changed.

Please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks

> The update is performed on a by-row basis. For every inserted, modified, and deleted row, the Update method determines the type of change that has been performed on it

Comment: I updated the question.

I correctly understood that this method iterates through all the rows of the data source and updates only the changed ones?

For greater efficiency, you should use other ways to update the row in the data source.

Will there be a better way? `private void dataGridView2_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)dataGridView2.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;
    DataRow[] dr = new DataRow[] { drv.Row };
            
    adapter.Update(dr);
}`

Comment: @eusataf , if you want to monitor the DataGridView data changes, I suggest you to use OnColumnStateChanged event (or others), and for greater efficiency, you should just make a  SqlCommand instance to execute a single sql command.